# How to use AUC packet? to calculate AUC

Tags: classification, training-data, caret, auc

## I train and make prediction with the following example :

[image]

=======================
The outputs are :

[image]

and :

[image]

Now I need to calculate AUC using the AUC package, but I can't quite understand how to do it?

auc(roc(????, ?????))

Thanks
Manel

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be :

library(AUC) 

auc(roc(testing$Class, prediction$R))  # I get as an answer the "AUC"

result.auc <- auc(prediction$M, testing$Class)

result.roc <- roc(testing$Class, prediction$M)

plot(result.roc, print.thres="best", print.thres.best.method="closest.topleft") # plot the curve

**You can comment on the solution**, please¡¡¡¡

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, one possible solution is :